# Error: sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30

Tags: python, flask

I received this issue while developing a system using flask, `flask-sqlalchemy` , `flask-login` and `SocketIO`, and I was the only one on the server.

I Thought that flask-login or `SocketIO` were involved or causing the system to go overflow

but I have tried many things including removing both from the system and the system still gets overflow on the 10-15th refresh while I'm the only user on it.

Apparently, `flask-SqlAlchemy` fails to close the connection with the database which causes it to pile up and crashes.

Here is how I set up the Database:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,jsonify
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from modals import *
​
# Configure app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='some secret'
app.config['PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy()
​
DBstring = "" # hidden
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= DBstring
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
​
# Initialize login manager
login = LoginManager(app)
login.init_app(app)
​
```

Not sure what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by merging the code in `modals.py` which contains all the classes with the  main file which is `main.py`

Apparently, there is some circular issue with flask.

I still not sure why is this happening? Why connection to the database fail to be closed if the `classes` were in another file?

Hopefully, someone would explain this to us.